# Cauchy's Integral Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to understand Cauchy's Integral Theorem which states

$$
\int_\gamma f(z)\,dz = 0.
$$

If function $f(z)$ is holomorphic (has no singularities) within the area contained by the contour $\gamma$. I understand the proof comes from Green's theorem, but I don't understand conceptually why this is true. What exactly does the complex contour integral measure? It's not area, is it?

Comment: I think you're leaving out some rather important assumption on $\,\gamma\,$ which are rather important for Green's Theorem, too. And no: the contour integral does not measure, in general, the area that $\,\gamma\,$ incloses, in general. What you have here, in short, is that a holomorphic function...etc. (conditions of CIT) has a potential in that zone (if you want to look at it as a 2-variable function) and is thus independent of the path.

Comment: This theorem is almost trivial when the function can be expressed by convergent power series, e.g. sin $z$.

Comment: @DonAntonio Sir, i am having difficulty in understanding complex integrals. I get the point on how things are and how things are defined but i don't get the intuition. What do you suggest?

Comment: @HarshVardhanSingh Remember that we can identify $\;\Bbb C\;$ with $\;\Bbb R^2\;$, and then complex integral, in its basic definition, is a real line integral in $\;\Bbb R^2\;$. That's probably one of the easiest ways to help intuition here. Thus you can think of analytic functions as of conservative fields and etc.

Comment: Thanks @DonAntonio sir for replying. means a lot to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not area.  You can think of it this way: for each infinitesimal segment of the curve, you multiply (as complex numbers) the displacement $dz$ by the function $f(z)$, and then you add those all up.  This is made rigorous by a definition in terms of Riemann sums.  They are really the same Riemann sums that you saw in calculus, but here there is no interpretation in terms of area.

Comment: This is essentially the definition of line integral in complex analysis. It has to be more than that , shouldn't it be ?

Comment: @HarshVardhanSingh I was answering the question "What exactly does the complex contour integral measure? It's not area, is it?".  Yes, there is a lot more to it.

Comment: Sir, @Robert Israel , i am learning complex analysis and just not able to get the intuition of how things are in complex analysis . what do you suggest ?

Answer (score 5):

Conceptually, Cauchy's integral theorem comes from the fact that it is trivially true for $f$ on the form $f(z)=az+b$, by explicit integration – and the fact that holomorphicity means that $f$ “almost” has that form locally around each point. To turn that into a proof requires some careful estimates of the wrongness of that “almost” statement.

I published such a proof in American Math Monthly back in 2008, only to discover that R. Výborný had published essentially the same proof back in 1979. Rather embarassing – but I still think my proof is quite readable, so it is [available](http://www.math.ntnu.no/~hanche/art/goursat/) from my homepage.