# Can this contour integral be solved easily?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have$$\int_{\gamma}\frac{z+1}{z(4z^2-1)^2}dz $$
where ${\gamma}$ is the positively oriented circle about i with radius 1/2.

$${\gamma}(t) = i +1/2e^{it}, 0  \leq t  \leq 2 \pi$$.

I believe cauchy's integral formula does not apply in this case because the root +- 0.5 is not within the contour. So how does one go about solving this?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/179181/cauchys-integral-theorem?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contour doesn't contain poles $z=0,\pm\dfrac12$, then the integral is zero by Cauchy's integral formula.